# How can I generate random number and put it into the variable like A1,A'1,B1,B'1

Tags: r

[image]

Hi i am new to R language , how can i generate the value and put it into the columns and rows. like

|  | On Time | Late | Satisfied | Not satisfied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rapid Train | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.2 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It depends on the type of random numbers you want.  You can sample from a uniform distribution using `runif()` or from a normal distribution using `rnorm()`. or you can sample from a population using `sample()`.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen am i able to assign each value to a specific variables ? and the row that i mentioned above are having the range from 0 to 1 and row for satisfied and not satisfied also got the same range

Comment: `df$Late <- runif(nrow(df))`, if assigning to the dataframe (df) is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
OnTime <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # generates 10 random numbers between 0 and 100
Late <- sample.int(100, 10) # generates 10 random integers between 1 and 100
Satisfied <- runif(5) # generates 5 random numbers from 0 to 1
```

Comment: am i able to assign each value to a specific variables ?

Comment: The row that i mentioned above are having the range from 0 to 1 and row for satisfied and not satisfied also got the same range.

Comment: @Hafiz Yes. My example creates vectors but you can assign it as u wish. For numbers between 0 and 1 use `runif(n)` where n is the amount of numbers to be generated.

Comment: one more question sir. if i already generated 4 numbers for example i got 0,0.1,0.2,0.4 . Then how can i declare the value is A1,A2,A3,A4? is there any methods to do it ? or i just have to put the comments?

Comment: `A1 <- 0` `A2 <- 0.1` etc.. Read about variable assignment https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_variables.htm Also if you found my answer correct accept it please :)